# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [383] did not match expected type

Tags: arrays, spring-mvc

Here is my service:

```
@Override
public List<Dmsapphistoryhead> readDmsapphistoryheadfromUserdocorg(long userdocorg) {
    Pageable topTen = new PageRequest(0, 5);
    return dmsapphistoryheadRepo.readuserdocorg(userdocorg, topTen);
}
```

Here is my Repo:

```
public interface DmsapphistoryheadRepo extends JpaRepository<Dmsapphistoryhead, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT d "
        + "FROM Dmsapphistoryhead d , Dmsuserdocorg a "
        + "WHERE d.userdocorg.userdocorg = a.userdocorg "
        + "AND d.userdocorg = :userdocorg")
    List<Dmsapphistoryhead> readuserdocorg(@Param("userdocorg") long userdocorg, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a more detailed stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [383] did not match expected type [com.apex.entity.Dmsuserdocorg (n/a)]

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenkoi I added the detailed stack trace.